# Returning a user friendly error message to client, from a web service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, .net-2.0

I need to return an error message to the client, if they have entered invalid data when calling my web service. So if my code is:

```
    If Not IsNumeric(strOrderID) Then
    Throw New SoapException("Invalid Order ID", SoapException.ClientFaultCode)
End If
```

I get a web page saying:
***System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Invalid Order ID
   at Service.GetHeaderValues(String strOrderID)***

Is there a way to display a more user friendly error message (such as a message box or just the words "Invalid Order ID")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My syntax might be off a bit, but you can use something like

```
return <err>ex.message</err>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to catch the exception at the client and handle it appropriately (display message, log it, whatever).

The WebService would/could never "show" anything to the user itself.